# Trying to get total sum based on months on ApexCharts with Php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, chart.js, apexcharts

I'm trying to display with [ApexCharts](https://apexcharts.com/javascript-chart-demos/area-charts/spline/) the total sum from DB based on date month and display into ApexCharts, but what i have tried is not working, im new with this, see the mysql db image and apexcharts link to see how is working and what i want to achive. Any help appreciated.

My Myqsl DB:
[See image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/loB1A.png)

getchart Php Code:

```
    $stats = array();

    $query = "SELECT SUM(totalprice), `timestamp` AS sum FROM `orders`";
    $statement = $db->query($query);

    while ($row = $db->fetch($statement))
    {

          $row_array  = $row['sum'];
          $row_array  = $row['timestamp'];
         array_push($stats,$row_array);

    }
echo json_encode($stats);
```

Js Code:

```
$.getJSON('../../shop/js/chart/getchart.php', function (json) {
    var options = {
        series: [{
            name: 'sales',
            data: json
        }],
        chart: {
            type: 'area',
            height: 350,
            stacked: false,
        },
        stroke: {
            show: true,
            curve: 'smooth',
            lineCap: 'butt',
            colors: undefined,
            width: 3,
            dashArray: 0,
        },
        markers: {
            size: 4,
            colors: ["#765be6"],
            strokeColors: "#fff",
            strokeWidth: 1,
            hover: {
                size: 7,
            }
        },
        fill: {
            type: 'gradient',
            gradient: {
                shade: 'dark',
                gradientToColors: ['#03adf7'],
                shadeIntensity: 5,
                inverseColors: true,
                type: 'vertical',
                opacityFrom: .7,
                opacityTo: .8,
            },
        },
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: false
        },
        plotOptions: {
            bar: {
                horizontal: false,
                columnWidth: '25%',
                endingShape: 'rounded'
            },
        },
        responsive: [{
            breakpoint: 480,
            options: {
                legend: {
                    position: 'bottom',
                    offsetX: 0,
                    offsetY: 0
                }
            }
        }],
        xaxis: {
            categories: ['Ian', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
        },
        colors: ['#765be6'],

    };
    var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#sales"), options);
    chart.render();
});
```

Comment: Your field alias is for the wrong field and there is no group by in your sql either. It would be great if you could describe what your exact problem is. Is it just the query that's wrong? If so, pls follow this guidance to improve your question and get rid of the unnecessary code and tags: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: The problem is i can't figure'it out how to query the values on sql & the ApexChatrs JS to work with those values totalprice and timestamp

Comment: Then I suggest you ask two separate questions: 1) fix sql 2) after fixing the sql try if you can make it work with your chart and if you cannot, then ask about creating the chart based on the data. This way your questions will be focused and you will be able to provide a more detailed description as to what went wrong. In its current format, you are dumping code on us and says that it does not work. Not particularly great for providing a starting point for us.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to initialize `option.series.data` with *totals* and with *timestamps* in a mixed way. Just separate them!

Place *timestamps* in the `option.xaxis.categories` or in the `option.labels`([check this](https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/labels/)). In the `option.series.data` you need to store *total sums* only!

Go through your ApexChart [example](https://apexcharts.com/javascript-chart-demos/area-charts/spline/) more carefully. There is the same way implementation.